# HTML table to Excel: writing to specific cells

Tags: excel, asp-classic

im trying to import html table data to an excel file and have succeeded in doing so:

```
<BODY>
<td><input type="text" name="txtVendorName" id="txtVendorName" value="weee"/></td>
</BODY>

<%
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=excelfile.xls"
%>
```

however upon looking at the generated file closely, i noticed that the values are not actually written in any cell.

would you happen to know how i can "target" cells and write to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you are using an input tag just write the text in the td like so:

```
<BODY>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>wee</td>
</tr>
</table>
</BODY>

<%
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=excelfile.xls"
%>
```

another method is to use the Jet OLE DB Provider 4.0 [like here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326548/en-us)